# Is it possible to call JS file in Event Receiver?

Tags: 2013, javascript, event-receivers

Is it possible to call JavaScript file in any of the events in event receiver in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You **can not run JS code** because the event receiver is not running in the *HTTP Context*.

You can run your javascript code from the newForm or a custom newform instead, maybe before the event (handled by the event receiver) fire.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed in Web Browser. It interacts with objects in DOM as well as uses functionality supported by Browsers.

You should re-write what you have in JavaScript.

**You can try below code - It is not tested**

```
public class CustomReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver    
{  
   private HttpContext currentContext;        
   static HttpContext _stCurrentContext;        

   public CustomReceiver()        
   {            
       currentContext = HttpContext.Current;         
   }  

   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)        
   {                        
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);

        _stCurrentContext = currentContext;
        if (_stCurrentContext != null)
        { 
           _stCurrentContext.Response.Write("<script>alert('JavaScript Invoked');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```